# How to handle errors while scraping anchors

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, anchor

I need to **scrape** h2 and h3 anchors on some websites.
I keep getting errors and this piece of code is not handling it correctly (it just stops instead of continuing scraping).
I need a better way of handling errors.
And if possible of more robust approach in general (scraping).

```
for url in urls:
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
    except:
        print('error '+url)
        pass
    

    for sub_heading in soup.find_all('h2'): 
           with open('output.csv', 'a') as output:
               output.write('\n')
               output.write("h2 ;"+url +";"+ sub_heading.text)        

    for sub_heading in soup.find_all('h3'):
           with open('output.csv', 'a') as output:
               output.write('\n')
               output.write("h3 ;"+url +";"+ sub_heading.text)
```

Comment: What sort of problem are you trying to avoid? The basic problem here is that ignoring errors will make at least the second and possibly both variables uninitialized; you can't just plunge ahead and pretend the error didn't happen. But how far to scale back also depends on what you want to accomplish. Abandoning the current page in case of errors will never fail, but presumably you have some sort of requirement to continue anyway. Please [edit] to clarify this, and at least reason broadly about why and how you think you can handle invalid return data.

Comment: "Abandoning the current page in case of errors will never fail" That would actually be acceptable: abandon the current page in case of error, print an error message and move on to the next url

Comment: The trivial change is to replace `pass` with `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted by @tripleee, you should edit the question as to provide us at the very least with the description of the errors that are blocking your code.

However, as a general rule, you should avoid try/excepting everything without further specifying the type of error that you are handling. In particular, at the moment you are capturing

```
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
```

which is likely to fail if either i) `url` is invalid, or ii) `lxml` fails to parse the text page. In both cases, you should better design the code in order for it not to happen (i.e., purge the `urls` list from invalid urls beforehand) without using a try/except. If that proves to be impossible, you should at least specify the errors handled (e.g. `except ConnectionError:`).

Finally, I strongly suggest you to use the `csv` package to write csv files in python, and to close the files every time you stop writing on them. Below I try to provide a MWE based on the elements that you have provided:

```
import csv
import requests    
with open('output.csv', 'a') as out: # here I open the file only once
    outwriter = csv.writer(out)
    for url in urls:
        try:
            req = requests.get(url) 
            soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
            for sub_heading in soup.find_all('h2'): # these are all h2s, if any
                row = ['h2', url, sub_heading.text]
                outwriter.writerow(row)
            for sub_heading in soup.find_all('h3'): # these are all h3s, if any
                row = ['h3', url, sub_heading.text]
                outwriter.writerow(row)
        except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: # I am only capturing invalid url error: in case you happen to have more, be sure to capture them one by one
            print('Invalid Url: ' + url)
    out.close() # close the output file
```